# Use login credentials for NetworkManager connection, preferably encrypted

Tags: login, network-manager, gnome-keyring, nmcli

I am wondering if it is possible to use the login credentials to connect to a wireless WPA2 connection in NetworkManager, e.g. using PEAP.
I need this for any new users. So they should be able to login, Them their login credential should not just be used to login, but also to connect to the WiFi.  I found something about using gnome keyring, but not sure how to approach it...

Comment: Is this what you need? Settings > Network > Wired : https://www.uio.no/english/services/it/network/student-residential-network/instructions/nm/4802.1x.png

Comment: No, I need something similar to this: https://bkhome.org/news/201909/encrypted-passwords-for-networkmanager.html

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 btw